# R Currency() changing only one Column

Tags: r, currency, formattable

Hey im new to R and wondering how i can with currency() of the package formattable format only 1 column.

`matrix <- currency(matrix)` working

`currency(matrix[,2])` working

BUT

```
matrix[,2] <- currency(matrix[,2])
```

OR

```
matrix[1,2] <- currency(matrix[1,2])
```

doesn't change anything in matrix

edit:
[My Problem in a nutshell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfRAJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `formattable` adds some attributes and `matrix` cannot have those attributes.  An option is to convert to `data.frame`

```
library(formattable)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix)
df1[,2] <- currency(df1[,2])
df1
#  V1     V2  V3
#1  1 $10.00 100
#2  2 $20.00 200
#3  3 $30.00 300
#4  4 $40.00 400
```

#### data

```
matrix <- cbind(1:4, c(10, 20, 30, 40), c(100, 200, 300, 400))
```

Comment: First of all thanks for taking time and im very sorry for the waste because i swaped [ and (. To be sure i looked up if i didnt in my console but i did all the time absolutly the same u wrote. the problem is that currency(matrix[,2]) is returning the expected value but i cannot write it in the matrix. Do u have any ideas why?

Comment: @tobu280 thank you for the message.  I updated with an example

Comment: Thank you very much this was the Problem! Didnt know that theres a problem with different Types in Matrix. Thank you for taking the Time!